# WeatherCast Application Angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a problem with my weather cast app in angular material. I don't know how to put the image of the current condition weather (ex: "Today is sunny" and it need to appear the icon of the "sun"). I have did a thing like this, but it doesn't work. This is a part of my weather-app.html :

```
  <p>Icon:{{weatherDays.list[1].weather[0].icon}}</p>
  <p>Temperature: 
   {{weatherDays.list[1].main.temp}}°C</p>
  <p>Minimum temperature: {{weatherDays.list[1].main.temp_min}}°C</p>
  <p>Maximum temperature: {{weatherDays.list[1].main.temp_max}}°C</p>
  <p>Description: {{weatherDays.list[1].weather[0].description}}</p>
```

The `Temp,min,max` and `description` it works, but I don't know how to make the image icon work to.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `img` tag inside of your paragraph and on it bind `[src]="weatherDays.list[1].weather[0].icon"` if that is the place where you have you icon

Comment: I wrote this :  <p>Icon:<img src="{{weatherDays.list[0].weather[0].icon}}"/></p>, it apear something but  it not apear the photo and in console apear this error: 04d:1 GET http://localhost:4200/04d 404 (Not Found)